# Отметить checkbox по value

Tags: jquery

Есть checkboxlist такого html типа

```
<div id="sel_city" class=" select_cities"><label><input type="checkbox" class="select_cities_inpt" name="ClientsObjectType[0][options_cities][]" value="86" id="clientsobjecttype-0-options-cities-86"><span> Киевский</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="select_cities_inpt" name="ClientsObjectType[0][options_cities][]" value="87" id="clientsobjecttype-0-options-cities-87"><span> Малиновский</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="select_cities_inpt" name="ClientsObjectType[0][options_cities][]" value="88" id="clientsobjecttype-0-options-cities-88"><span> Приморский</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="select_cities_inpt" name="ClientsObjectType[0][options_cities][]" value="89" id="clientsobjecttype-0-options-cities-89"><span> Суворовский</span></label>
```

В переменной `var sel_ci = $(".var_city_id").prop("value");` у меня есть значения - 87/88/89. Можно ли отметитить чекбокс, value которого равно переменной `var sel_ci` ?

Comment: можно. но где ваш код?

Comment: на случай если у вас это делается для инициализации и выставления изначальных чекбоксов при редактировании формы, то лучше это делать на стороне сервера, а не расставлять галки на клиенте.

Comment: ну по хорошему - распарсить строку 87/88/89 при помощи slice("/") и потом пройтись по полученному массиву выставляя у checkbox[value=str_val] checked атрибут.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($('#sel_city input[type=checkbox]'), function(i, item) {
    if ($(item).val() == sel_ci) 
        $(item).prop('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: там `id` элементы строится на основании `value`, можно ничего не перебирать, а просто обратиться к элементу по `ID`

Comment: Можно и по ID, если список большой